Kafka with Zookeeper connections issue on EKS
I am quite new to Kafka.
I want to deploy Kafka with Zookeeper on EKS cluster. [without Kraft]
I am using bitnami helm charts for the same.
Here are followed steps:
Step1:
I have deployed zookeeper chart using command:
helm install zookeeper bitnami/zookeeper --set replicaCount=3 --set auth.enabled=false --set allowAnonymousLogin=true --set persistence.accessModes={ReadWriteOnce} --set persistence.size=1Gi --set podLabels."app\.kubernetes\.io/version"="1.0"  -n kafka

Chart was deployed successfully.
Step2:
Now I am trying to deployed bitnami kafka chart [without Kraft]
helm install kafka bitnami/kafka --set zookeeper.enabled=true \
                              --set controller.replicaCount=0 \
                              --set replicaCount=3 \
                              --set kraft.enabled=false \
                              --set autoCreateTopicsEnable=true \
                              --set persistence.accessModes={ReadWriteOnce} \
                              --set persistence.size=1Gi \
                              --set podLabels."app\.kubernetes\.io/version"="1.0" \
                              --set broker.replicaCount=1 \
                              --set externalZookeeper.servers=zookeeper.kafka.svc.cluster.local -n kafka

Chart was deployed successfully.
kubectl get svc -n kafka                                
NAME                       TYPE        CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                      AGE
kafka                      ClusterIP   172.20.126.198   <none>        9092/TCP                     68m
kafka-broker-headless      ClusterIP   None             <none>        9094/TCP,9092/TCP            68m
kafka-zookeeper            ClusterIP   172.20.38.52     <none>        2181/TCP                     68m
kafka-zookeeper-headless   ClusterIP   None             <none>        2181/TCP,2888/TCP,3888/TCP   68m
zookeeper                  ClusterIP   172.20.251.179   <none>        2181/TCP,2888/TCP,3888/TCP   68m
zookeeper-headless         ClusterIP   None             <none>        2181/TCP,2888/TCP,3888/TCP   68m


kubectl get po -n kafka                        
NAME                READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
kafka-broker-0      1/1     Running   0          59m
kafka-client        1/1     Running   0          22m
kafka-zookeeper-0   1/1     Running   0          69m
zookeeper-0         1/1     Running   0          69m
zookeeper-1         1/1     Running   0          69m
zookeeper-2         1/1     Running   0          69m

Step3: Send test message
After that I sent a test message to check the connection, which failed with error as:
kafkacat -b kafka.kafka.svc.cluster.local:9092 -t test-topic -P -f "Hello"
%3|1716630886.274|FAIL|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:kafka.kafka.svc.cluster.local:9092/bootstrap]: kafka.kafka.svc.cluster.local:9092/bootstrap: Failed to resolve 'kafka.kafka.svc.cluster.local:9092': Temporary failure in name resolution (after 0ms in state CONNECT)
%3|1716630888.275|FAIL|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:kafka.kafka.svc.cluster.local:9092/bootstrap]: kafka.kafka.svc.cluster.local:9092/bootstrap: Failed to resolve 'kafka.kafka.svc.cluster.local:9092': Temporary failure in name resolution (after 0ms in state CONNECT, 1 identical error(s) suppressed)
^C^C^C
% ERROR: Local: Host resolution failure: kafka.kafka.svc.cluster.local:9092/bootstrap: Failed to resolve 'kafka.kafka.svc.cluster.local:9092': Temporary failure in name resolution (after 0ms in state CONNECT)
% ERROR: Local: All broker connections are down: 1/1 brokers are down : terminating

I can see following warning in kafka-broker-0 pod logs
[2024-05-25 09:41:10,845] WARN [RequestSendThread controllerId=100] Controller 100's connection to broker kafka-broker-0.kafka-broker-headless.kafka.svc.cluster.local:9094 (id: 100 rack: null) was unsuccessful (kafka.controller.RequestSendThread)
java.io.IOException: Connection to kafka-broker-0.kafka-broker-headless.kafka.svc.cluster.local:9094 (id: 100 rack: null) failed.
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClientUtils.awaitReady(NetworkClientUtils.java:71)
    at kafka.controller.RequestSendThread.brokerReady(ControllerChannelManager.scala:298)
    at kafka.controller.RequestSendThread.doWork(ControllerChannelManager.scala:251)
    at org.apache.kafka.server.util.ShutdownableThread.run(ShutdownableThread.java:131)
    

Do you know how I can fix this?
Any help is much appreciated.

Helm is fine, but why not use Strimzi?

@OneCricketeer Not much experience with operator or kafka overall. So trying this approach.
